# Where change settings data in Filemaker using fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, filemaker, fullcalendar-3

I am using fullCalendar` in a Filemaker DB, and I have learned how to use my own data for the calendar, and how to build scripts to add events.

Now I would like to change something in the calendar layout. For example, I want to use locale data `it-IT`.

Another problem is that, even if current data is stored, when I open the calendar it goes to an April day (we are in December now!).

I don't know where to go to change settings for calendar, I don't know where to change settings I have seen on calendar documentation.

Attached a layout where can find any settings, but I cannot find `"locale"` for example, to change international setting.

Hope I have explained right, thanks.

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        height:800,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        eventColor: '**Data3**',
        allDaySlot: true,
        minTime: '8:00:00',
        maxTime: '21:00:00',
        weekends:true,
        businessHours: true,
        businessHours: {
            start: '08:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
            end: '19:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
            dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
         // (Monday-Thursday in this example)
        },
        firstDay: 1,
        allDaySlot:true,
        allDayText: "all day",
        defaultDate: '**Data2**', 
        slotDuration: '00:15:00',
        slotLabelInterval: '00:30:00',
        slotLabelFormat: 'hh:mm',
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
            **Data1**
        ],
        editable: true,
        eventResize: function( event, delta, revertFunc) {
            var id = event.id;
            var start = event.start.format();
            var end = event.end.format();
            var theList =  [id,start,end];
            var doThis = "fmp://$/**FileName**?script=updateAppointment&param=" + theList;
            window.location = doThis; 
        },
        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
            var id = event.id;
            var start = event.start.format();
            var end = event.end.format();
            var theList =  [id,start,end];
            var doThis = "fmp://$/**FileName**?script=updateAppointment&param=" + theList;
            window.location = doThis;
        }
    });
});
```

---

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                                locale: 'it',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
                },
                height:800,

                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                eventColor: '**Data3**',
                allDaySlot: true,
                minTime: '8:00:00',
                maxTime: '21:00:00',
                    weekends:true,
                businessHours: true,
                businessHours: {
```

---

This is the HTML Field where I have added Script fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />


<style> **CSS1**  </style>
<style>**CSS2** </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>

<script>**jQueryMin**</script>
<script>**JS2** </script>
<script>**JS1**</script>
<script> **JSFunction**</script>
<script>**fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js**</script>
</html>
```

Filemaker config:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204146/discussion-on-question-by-lolli-group-where-change-settings-data-in-filemaker-us).

Answer (score 1):

For the opening date: you must remove the parameter

```
  defaultDate: '**Data2**
```

if it is not filled in by default, the current date is displayed
for local, just put

```
local:"fr",
```

"fr" or "en" or other language

I hope my answer does not arrive too late